# How to Populate MessagesList UI with messages i got from PubNub fetchMessagesHistory function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, pubnub

I am able to fetch the history messages for a channel and I need to put the array of those messages into the prebuilt UI MessagesList that they gave me, they mention in their docs that I should override or subclass but how to do that exactly? I am still a beginner with swift, I'm using UIKit not SwiftUI. thanks in advance

Comment: I am consulting with the PN Chat engineering team on this. You could email support@pubnub.com with the same question and get the answer very quickly. If you do that, please include link to this post so we can post an answer back here, too.

Comment: I already sent an email and the response I got is that the MessageList has a view model that shows me the messages but I couldn't find that and it's not clear how exactly it shows me the messages, I will send them an email again ok

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, [MessageList](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/components/ios/ui-components-ios#messagelist) is an inherited class of [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/), and is used to display a list of stored message objects. The mention of [overriding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html#ID196) core functionality is discussing using the default `MessageListComponentViewModel` to display the messages of a particular channel. The docs are explaining that you only need to use the `MessageListComponentViewModel` to obtain the history messages of a channel, but that you could also add your own overridden functionalities from the base `UIViewController` if wanted to do so.

For the problem at hand, after consulting with our PubNub engineers, you'll need to populate your local database with data. For example, if you want Messages to appear for a Channel, then you can use either the `load(messages:)` [method](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/components/ios/data-components-ios#parameters-36) if you have Messages already created locally, or `thesyncRemoteMessages(_:)` [method](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/components/ios/data-components-ios#parameters-39) if you want to sync messages from PubNub storage.

I strongly recommend following the [Getting Started](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/components/ios/get-started-ios) guide. The guide shows how to create local objects for use with Message List UI in a real chat application, and you can use the Message Input (at the bottom of the UI) to [publish messages](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/components/ios/get-started-ios#send-your-first-message).

If you would like another example, you can follow PubNub's [tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/simple-chat-app-ios/) on adding iOS Chat Components to an existing application.

Comment: @AbanoubAshraf I think in your case you do NOT have messages already created locally, that would be used if you wanted to pre-populate the message window, for example if you had some default welcome messages for every user.  You want to call the syncRemoveMessages(_:) message to pull your historical messages.  Anything you publish from the message input will automatically update the local database